# PrimeNG p-multiSelect did not display selected values

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

My `p-multiSelect` in the tamplate:

```
<p-multiSelect
    name="selectedItens" 
    [options]="vlans" 
    [(ngModel)]="selectedItens" 
    optionLabel="name" 
></p-multiSelect>
```

In the ngOnInit I havet this code to populate the `selectedItens`:

```
this._myService
.getSelectedItens(this.myDto.id)
.pipe()
.subscribe(data => {
    this.selectedItens = data["result"];
});
```

The `selectedItens` is an object like this:

```
name: string | undefined;
active: Boolean | undefined;
id: number;
```

I checked the return value witch console.log and everything looks right, but my multSelect look like this:
[image]

`data["result"]` sample:

> 0: {name: "V-123", active: true, id: 3}
>
> 1: {name: "V-832", active: false, id: 333}
>
> 2: {name: "V-220", active: false, id: 6}

**All options appear normally in the list, but when I click on to select any more fields the checkbox is not checked despite working (the item clicked is added to the array).**

**If I remove the `[(ngModel)]="selectedItens"` everything works fine, but I need to show the itens that already beend selected.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I remove the [(ngModel)]="selectedItens" everything works fine

Because you are assigning whole array to `ngModel` so, that's not able to show proper `dropdown`(combo).

In your use case you need assign the selected value to **`[(ngModel)]`** not the entire list.

Here is the [**`stackBlitz`**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-multiselect-placeholder-d84vpm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your reference. Please try to make changes like below (P.S : working with hard coded values like below)

```
 this.selectedItem =  this.selectedItem.concat(this.vlans[1].value);
```

Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: I'm using p-multiSelect not p-dropdown, in multiSelect it should acept an array: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/multiselect

Comment: I followed you example in stackBlitz and it worked :)
I think it was not working before because I did not use the SeleteItem but a custom object.

Answer (score 0):

In another scenario, we need to assign the options again to reflect.

```
this.vlans = [...this.vlans];
```